# Sequence for numbers in a vector

Tags: c++, vector

```
void Numbers()
{

    do
    {
        cout << "Enter the value for the sequence: ";
        cin >> K;

            if ( K <= 3)
            {
                cout << "Write a bigger number!" << endl;
            }
    } while(K <= 3);

    cout << "Enter the first number: ";
    cin >> N;
}

double Sum()
{
    vector<double> arr(K);
    arr.push_back(N);

    for (int i=0; i < arr.size(); i++)
        arr.at(i)=i;

    cout << "Vector contains: ";
    for (int i=0; i < arr.size(); i++)
    cout << arr.at(i);


int main()
{
    Numbers();
    Sum();

    return 0;
}
```

Write a program that generates sequence of K (K > 3) numbers as follows:

The members of the above sequence are obtained as follows:

the first element is N;
the second one is N + 1;
the third - N * 2.
In other words, we consistently add 1 to each element and put it to the end of the sequence, then multiply it by 2 and again, put the product to the end of the sequence. Choose and implement a suitable data structure that can be used to generate the above sequence of numbers.

The users should enter values for K and first element N.

This is my current code(in the code above). I don`t realy know where to go from here onward to be completely honest. Any suggestions on how to create the sequence from the condition above?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn how to create a [mcve] of your own attempt to show us inside the question itself (as text), and describe what problems you have with it.

Comment: From the description it sounds like the third element is actually `(N+1)*2`, followed by `(N+1)*2+1`, and so on.

Comment: @molbdnilo ye, but i dont want to "hard-code" it if that makes sence..  I was kinda thinking of a function to auto calculate it if possible.

Comment: You don't have to hard-code this but is it what you want? N, N+1, (N+1)*2, (N+1)*2+1, ...?

Comment: @ImanKianrostami yes, thats the purpose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code to get what you want:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

vector<double> createOutputArray (int K, int N)
{
    vector<double> arr;
    int tmp = N;

    arr.push_back(tmp);
    for(int i=1; i+2<=K; i+=2)
    {
        arr.push_back(++tmp);
        arr.push_back(tmp * 2);
        tmp *= 2;
    }
    if(K % 2 == 0)
        arr.push_back(++tmp);

    return arr;
}

int main()
{
    int K;
    double N;
    do
    {
        cout << "Enter the value for the sequence: ";
        cin >> K;

        if ( K <= 3)
        {
            cout << "Write a bigger number!" << endl;
        }
    } while(K <= 3);

    cout << "Enter the first number: ";
    cin >> N;

    vector<double> output = createOutputArray(K, N);
    for (int i=0; i < output.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << output.at(i);
        if(i < output.size()-1)
            cout << ",";
        else
            cout << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one possibility, using a generator to produce the next element in the sequence.

```
class Seq
{
public:
    Seq(int n) : n(n) {}
    int operator*() const { return n; }
    Seq operator++(int)
    {
        Seq old(n);
        n = fns[fn](n);
        fn = 1 - fn;
        return old;
    }
private:
    int n;
    int fn = 0;
    std::function<int(int)> fns[2] = {[](int x) { return x + 1; },
                                      [](int x) { return x * 2; }};
};

int main()
{
    int N = 1;
    int K = 20;
    Seq seq(N);
    for (int i = 0; i < K; i++)
    {
        std::cout << *seq++ << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: can be `std::copy_n(Seq(N), K, std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "))`

Comment: what doest fns stand for ? and what libraries do you use

Comment: @Vap0ur3x It stands for "functions", and you need to include `<functional>`.